# Can we run selenium chromedriver test in headed mode. If yes what settings we need to do and where?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run the selenium test in headed mode. Now test running headless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChromeDriver always runs in headed mode by default, if you are running puppeteer, you need to pass a parameter when creating a new browser instance.
Ill google that and add it in a moment.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
```

If you are running selenium webDriver, it may behave the command line argument `--headless`, you can remove that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ChromeOptions.setHeadless(false) (https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setHeadless-boolean-)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me using python, by adding something like:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
# add more options...
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```